# Javascript equation producing incorrect value

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function which returns a result based on variables passed to it. It is giving incorrect values during calculation however.

I've narrowed the culprit to here:

```
Math.floor((obj.mem1.val1 + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2))
```

Which when replacing the variables from the code with their numeric values (yes, I've checked to ensure they are the correct values being passed to the equation) it is:

```
Math.floor((90 + 15) * (0.5343543))
```

Which should come out to equal `56` but instead is giving `4817`. I've even added in:

```
alert(Math.floor((90 + 15) * (0.5343543)))
```

Just to see if making the browser run the exact calculation manually yields the right number, but it still gives an alert box saying `4817`.

What could possibly be doing this? It's doing basic math wrong. Something I've always kind of trusted a computer to do correctly without fail.

**EDIT**

Sample code to show the error:

```
var obj = {
  "mem1": {
    "val1": "90" // <-- issue was ultimately here this value was being
                 //     populated from 
                 //     document.getElementById().innerHTML
                 //     elsewhere in the code, so it was saving a string
    },
  "mem2": {
    "something-passed-through-param": [
      { "val2": 0.5343543 }
      ]
    }
  };

function func(param, i, j) {
  var ret = Math.floor((obj.mem1.val1 + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2));
  return ret;
  }

// Correct code would have been:
var ret = Math.floor((Number(obj.mem1.val1) + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2));
```

Comment: Evidently something is not what you believe it to be.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we're essentially just playing a guessing game.

Comment: I ran the same code in the console and got 56. Something must be messing with your values.

Comment: Is `obj.mem1.val1` being converted to a number before being added to `i`?  It looks like your getting `('90' + 15) * (0.5343543)` but that comes out to `4817` or thereabouts.  Basically I think what you're really getting is concatenation.  `<string> + <number>` results in `+` being treated as a concatenation operator, not addition.  You're probably then trimming it somehow to three characters from the left.

Comment: As @JosephMarikle said. Looks like your 90 might be a string.

Comment: Oh, `901 * 0.5343543` would be 481

Comment: @JosephMarikle, it didn't show up in my debugging because I was displayng the numbers as strings to check them prior to calculation, but that's it. I just passed obj.mem1.val1 through Number() and it calculated correctly. I will update the question with sample code for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, the issue was that `obj.mem1.val1` was being passed to the calculation as a string, resulting in `('90' + 15) * (0.5343543)` or more likely `('90' + 1) * (0.5343543)`.  Casting it to a number corrects the issue.  This may be done like so:

```
Math.floor((+obj.mem1.val1 + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2))
```

or

```
Math.floor((Number(obj.mem1.val1) + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2))
```

and a few other ways.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, expression `Math.floor(("90"+"15") * (0.5343543));` gives `4817`

Answer (score 0):

use: Math.floor((obj.mem1.val1*1 + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2))

Comment: Personally I would prefer `Math.floor((+obj.mem1.val1 + i) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2)) `

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor(('90' + '15') * (0.5343543))` returns `4817`. This means you need to convert `obj.mem1.val1` as well as `i` into integers.

`Math.floor((parseInt(obj.mem1.val1) + parseInt(i)) * (obj.mem2[param][j].val2))` should work if that was your error.